# How to make ID what is returned by `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId` constant, so it is same in Compose and in Sent status of the email?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'am developing addon for outlook. So for it I am using office.js api. In my addon I want the option to open emails in new window. I store emails ID in db.

Problem is that I "grab" Id of email when it is in compose status, for example, emails ID is **`AAA`**. I press `sent` btn and email now in Sent folder.
As it should, then I want to open that email using my addon, but I could not, reason that id of that email is now **'BBB'**!
I checked it by pressing on that email in Outlook and calling this javascript code `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId` I found that email ID changed.

**Question is how to make ID what is returned by `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId` constant so is the same in `compose` and in `Sent` status of the email?**

In graph.api you have [immutable ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) but I do not see how to apply them in office.js.api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend calling the Save method before retrieving the item Id. For example, the `EntryID` property available in the Outlook object model is set when an item is saved to the store.

Also different Outlook clients will return the `itemId` in the protocol they leverage. REST and EWS item Ids are escaped differently which is causing the difference between the `itemId` for the same item.

The id returned by `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` is an EWS item id. You can convert it to rest/graph item id by using `Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId`.

In the desktop edition of Outlook the `EntryId` may be changed when an item is moved to another folder/store. Check it out whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable ids are Graph specific. Ids in EWS (that is what JS addins use) and MAPI (used by both Extended MAPI - native Outlook API - and by the Outlook Object Model) change when an item is moved.

Your best option is to add your own custom property to the item and then search for it when the item in moved to a different folder.

Comment: but it does not fix  the problem, because I need that EWS(what returned after `Office.context.mailbox.item.ItemId` call ) to use in `Office.context.mailbox.displayMessageFormAsync()` method to open it latter.

Comment: After you search for your custom property, you can grab the EWS id from the matching record returned by the search.

Comment: but this custom property is not added in Outlook email it only in my DB. How then I will find needed email? To get all emails I will use Graph API and call to `list emails` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-list-emails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript) but it will return list of emails but without my custom property.

Comment: Yes, you need to set that custom property on the email in Exchange server to be able to find by it later.

Comment: For example I have `MyCustomProperty` in records of my DB of emails. Property is uniq. So how I will find needed email ID? Graph API return only `itemEmail` what cannot be edited or hold extra prm.

Comment: Exchange server is outlook app and desktop outlook. I am developing as mentioned add-in for outlook . So I assume no exchange servers?

Comment: Outlook is on the client. JS addins and EWS only work against Exchange server on the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can get easily ItemId in compose mode. it's mean when you are creating a new mail you can get easily mailId.

> javascript

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(
function callback(result) {
    console.log(result.value)
});
```